# CleanWebPackPlugin Error :CleanwebpackPlugin is not a constructor

Tags: npm, webpack, plugins

Im trying to use this plugin: CleanWebpackPlugin.

But it's not running, i can see the Error: `"TypeError: CleanWebPackPlugin is not a constructor"`
even if i tried all upgrades from the github page: https://github.com/johnagan/clean-webpack-plugin/issues/106

this is my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "------",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server",
    "build": "webpack",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/----/--------.git"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/-----/-----/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/----/------#readme",
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "lazysizes": "^5.1.2",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "normalize.css": "^8.0.1",
    "react": "^16.11.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.11.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.7.2",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.7.1",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.7.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^9.6.5",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "css-loader": "^3.2.0",
    "cssnano": "^4.1.10",
    "fs-extra": "^8.1.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.8.0",
    "postcss-hexrgba": "^2.0.0",
    "postcss-import": "^12.0.1",
    "postcss-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "postcss-mixins": "^6.2.2",
    "postcss-nested": "^4.1.2",
    "postcss-simple-vars": "^5.0.2",
    "style-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "webpack": "^4.41.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.9",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.9.0"
  }
}
```

This is my webpack.config file

```
const currentTask = process.env.npm_lifecycle_event 
const path= require('path')
const {CleanWebPackPlugin} = require ('clean-webpack-plugin')



const postCSSPlugins = [
    require('postcss-import'),
    require('postcss-mixins'),
    require('postcss-simple-vars'),
    require('postcss-nested'),
    require('postcss-hexrgba'),
    require('autoprefixer')
]


let config = {
    entry:'./app/assets/scripts/App.js',
    module: {
        rules:[
            {
                test:/\.css$/i,
                use: ['style-loader','css-loader?url=false',
                {loader:'postcss-loader', options:{plugins: postCSSPlugins}}]
            }
        ]
    }
}

if (currentTask == 'dev'){

    config.output = {
        filename:'bundled.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname,'app')
    }
    config.devServer = {
        before: function(app,server){
            server._watch('./app/**/*.html')
        },
        contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'app'),
        hot:true,
        port:3000,
        host:'0.0.0.0'
    }
    config.mode = 'development'
}

if (currentTask == 'build') {

    config.output = {
        filename:'[name].[chunkhash].js',
        chunkFilename:'[name].[chunkhash].js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname,'dist')
    }
    config.mode = 'production'
    config.optimization = {
        splitChunks: {chunks: 'all'}
    }
    //config.plugins = [new CleanWebPackPlugin({dry:true, cleanAfterEveryBuildPatterns:['dist']})]
}

module.exports = config
```

I tried

```
const {CleanWebPackPlugin} = require ('clean-webpack-plugin')
```

and

```
const CleanWebPackPlugin = require ('clean-webpack-plugin')
```

I tried

```
config.plugins = [new CleanWebPackPlugin()]
```

and

```
config.plugins = [new CleanWebPackPlugin(['dist'])]
```

and

```
 config.plugins = [new CleanWebPackPlugin({dry:true, cleanAfterEveryBuildPatterns:['dist']})]
```

and finally when delete this line, its working, but not with this plugin...